# Multiple instances of Qt android application

Tags: android, c++, qt, android-manifest, qt6

I am trying to write an android application that opens PDF files (that is, it responds to PDF viewing intents). However, when I open the application while another instance is already open by clicking on a PDF file, the application crashes. It appears that the android version of Qt is not capable of handling multiple instances?
Here is a minimal reproducible code sample:

`main.cpp` file:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QPushButton>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QWidget container;
    QPushButton button("Click me", &container);
    container.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

`AndroidManifest.xml` file. This is the same as the default autogenerated manifest file by qt, except the intent-filters for PDF files:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="org.qtproject.example"
    android:installLocation="auto"
    android:versionCode="-- %%INSERT_VERSION_CODE%% --"
    android:versionName="-- %%INSERT_VERSION_NAME%% --">
    <!-- %%INSERT_PERMISSIONS -->
    <!-- %%INSERT_FEATURES -->
    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true" />
    <application
        android:name="org.qtproject.qt.android.bindings.QtApplication"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:label="-- %%INSERT_APP_NAME%% --"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:allowNativeHeapPointerTagging="false"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:fullBackupOnly="false">
        <activity
            android:name="org.qtproject.qt.android.bindings.QtActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|uiMode|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|layoutDirection|locale|fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|mcc|mnc|density"
            android:label="-- %%INSERT_APP_NAME%% --"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="unspecified"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.OPEN_DOCUMENT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="application/pdf" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="application/pdf" />
            </intent-filter>

          <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="-- %%INSERT_APP_LIB_NAME%% --" />

          <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.arguments"
                android:value="-- %%INSERT_APP_ARGUMENTS%% --" />

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.extract_android_style"
                android:value="minimal" />
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

If you open the app and then try to open another instance by clicking on a PDF file, it freezes and the only way to open it again is to close it from system menu. [This blog post](https://www.qt.io/blog/2018/01/16/sharing-files-android-ios-qt-app-part-2) suggests setting `android:launchMode:"singleInstance"` in the manifest file, but it is only a partial solution, because even with that when opening a PDF file from another application (e.g. google drive or telegram) still a new version of the application is created and it still crashes.